# Don't reset form values after submit

Tags: php, mysql, header, inputbox

After giving a preview by php header code, I want to not reset the input boxes? Thanks.
This is my simplified code:

```
#php Code 
if($_POST['pre']){

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $exp = $_POST['exp'];
    $alt = $_POST['alt'];
    if ( $tag == '' or $img == '' or $alt==''){

    }
    else{
    $_SESSION['pre'] = "<a href=" ;
    $_SESSION['pre'] .= "\"$link\"><img src=";
    $_SESSION['pre'] .= "\"$img\" alt=\"$alt\" ></a>";
    header("location: add_adv.php?show=on");
    }
}
```

## html Code

```
<table>
<tr><td id="title"><p>add</p></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td><form name="form2" method="post" action="">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" /> </td>
            <td>tag</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" name="img" id="img" /></td>
            <td>picture</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" name="link" id="link" /></td>
            <td>link</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" name="alt" id="alt" /></td>
            <td>alternative</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" name="exp" id="exp" /></td>
            <td>Expire</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input name="pre" type="submit" class="sub" id="pre" value="Preview">
              <input type="submit" name="add_adv" class="sub" id="add_adv" value="اضافه" /></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
      </form>
</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give all the input boxes a value attribute equal to the previously submitted value.

```
<td><input type="text" size="30" name="exp" id="exp" value="<?=$exp?>" /></td>
<td>Expire</td>
```

Comment: tnx dude it give me an idea ;)

Comment: Then find another way to make the inputs have the correct value. The server will have to return the submitted values one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

```
// make public
$tag = $link = $img = $exp = $alt = null;

if($_POST['pre']){

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $exp = $_POST['exp'];
    $alt = $_POST['alt'];
    if ( $tag == '' or $img == '' or $alt==''){

    }
    else{
    $_SESSION['pre'] = "<a href=" ;
    $_SESSION['pre'] .= "\"$link\"><img src=";
    $_SESSION['pre'] .= "\"$img\" alt=\"$alt\" ></a>";
    header("location: add_adv.php?show=on");
    }
}
```

Comment: i use this var out side this php block

Answer (score 0):

Very simple method

Add below script in bottom of your page

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/akjpro/form-anticlear/base.js"></script>
```

Then add 'form-anticlear' class to your form

```
<form class="form-anticlear">
   <input type="text" name="myText">
</form>
```

Visit for advanced options : https://github.com/akjpro/form-anticlear